# Check if first column has 4 digits and if not pad with zeroes

Tags: bash, awk

I'd like to check if the first column has 4 digits, and if not then add `0` in front so all should be 4 digits (using awk, bash, etc.):

```
T12FT 19/11/19 2000 
T12FT 18/12/19 2040 

T5 19/11/19 2000 
T5 18/12/19 2080 

T0015 19/11/19 2050 
T0015 18/12/19 2060
```

I'd like to get following output:

```
T0012FT 19/11/19 2000 
T0012FT 18/12/19 2040 

T0005 19/11/19 2000 
T0005 18/12/19 2080 

T0015 19/11/19 2050 
T0015 18/12/19 2060
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

You could do it with sed:

```
sed -E '
    s/[[:digit:]]/000&/
    s/[[:digit:]]*([[:digit:]]{4})/\1/
' infile
```

The first substitution inserts `000` in front of the first digit in the line, so the intermediate state is

```
T00012FT 19/11/19 2000 
T00012FT 18/12/19 2040 

T0005 19/11/19 2000 
T0005 18/12/19 2080 

T0000015 19/11/19 2050 
T0000015 18/12/19 2060
```

The second substitution then retains the last four digits of the first group of digits:

```
T0012FT 19/11/19 2000 
T0012FT 18/12/19 2040 

T0005 19/11/19 2000 
T0005 18/12/19 2080 

T0015 19/11/19 2050 
T0015 18/12/19 2060
```

Comment: perhaps delete just the leading zeros `sed -E 's/[0-9]+/000&/;s/0+([0-9]{4})/\1/'`